# When does the unique functor have a left and right adjoint?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small category. Also, let $1$ be the discrete category with on one object.When does the unique functor $!:\mathcal{C}\to 1$ have a left and right adjoint?

Comment: Aren't those just initial and terminal object?

Comment: Are you saying that $!$ has a left adjoint if $\mathcal{C}$ has an initial object and a right adjoint if $\mathcal{C}$ has a terminal object.

Comment: Well, by definition of a left adjoint $\operatorname{Hom}(I,X)\cong \operatorname{Hom(1,1)}$, which translates to "for every object $X$ in $\mathcal C$, there is a unique morphism $I\to X$". And similarly for right adjoint.

Comment: Then, how would I define the functors. I am confused on this. Would we define the left adjoint to be  $F:1\to \mathcal{C}$ where $F(1)$ is the initial object and $F(id_1)$ to be the identity map from the initial object to itself? Similarly for the right adjoint?

Comment: Yes. $\hphantom{}$

Comment: Another way to see it is by noticing that $1\simeq \mathcal C^{\varnothing}$ where $\varnothing$ is the empty category, and then $!:\mathcal C \to 1$ is the 'constant diagram' functor. Now you are in the general case of the definition of limits and colimits.